# how to do Image coordinate normalization before extract Zernike moments from an image?

Tags: matlab, mapping, normalization

i want to extract zernike moments from an image.
It is written in the papers that before extracting the Zernike moments, the image must be mapped into a unit circle.
I don't know how to do that.
Can anyone guide me?
Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: Which paper are you referring to?

Comment: For example, an article I just recently found it:[link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.100.528&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: Equation 2.9 gives you the transformation.

Comment: @CrisLuengo sorry if  My question is very simple. But it's not clear to me. it says that the image should be mapped into a unit circle, does it mean that the 100*100 image has to be converted into a `2/sqrt(2)*2/sqrt(2)`  image? What does that image mean?

Comment: It means you put the x,y coordinates for each pixel through equation 2.9, getting the normalized r,phi coordinates out. Those coordinates you use in the equation for the moments.